# Is there a lightweight way to test C code on Android?

Tags: applications

I want to write and run small general purpose C code snippets on my Android phone. These will primarily be data structures and algorithm implementations. Is there a lightweight  and quick way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth a try to install [Android IDE](http://www.android-ide.com/) (AIDE) - to quote a brief summary:

> AIDE is an integrated development environment (IDE) for developing
> real Android Apps directly on Android devices. AIDE supports the full
> edit-compile-run cycle

However, typing on a device might make it cumbersome unless its a tablet form factor with bluetooth keyboard attached to save the pain in typing.

## Edit

As per @Izzy's comment below, [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en) is another such app, this one points to *Google Play Store*, however I got a 500 error trying to access the page below within the comment! Cheers for that \o/

Comment: Similar solution you might want to include: [Terminal IDE](http://www.appbrain.com/app/terminal-ide/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside). Even has midnight commander included, plus rsync, git, etc.pp. Of course also the gcc, make, javac, & Co :)

Comment: I looked at Terminal IDE but screenshots suggest that its extremely unsuitable for phones.

Answer (score 1):

Lightest way is to not install anything at all and simply use a website, such as [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/).

Comment: What about - [Compilr](http://compilr.com/) or [Cloud9](https://c9.io/)? :)